# How to add a click action to ToolStripMenuItem.DropDown items that were created dynamically?

Tags: c#, winforms

So I creating some items in favsToolStripMenuItem.DropDown (*ToolStripMenuItem*) based on a file:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("text.ini"))
{
  while (true)
  {
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    if (line== null)
      break;
    favsToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.Items.Add(line);
  }
}
```

But how can I add click event for them? I want a click event based on the item's name (text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stub out your click method:

```
private void DropDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  ToolStripItem tsi = sender as ToolStripItem;
  if (tsi != null) {
    MessageBox.Show(tsi.Text);
  }
}
```

and then use the Add parameter that includes the Event Handler:

```
favsToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.Items.Add(line, null, DropDown_Click);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assign the event when creating each menu item.

```cs
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("text.ini"))
{
    while (true)
    {
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    if (line== null)
        break;

    ToolStripMenuItem menu = new ToolStripMenuItem(line);
    menu.Click += new EventHandler(menu_Click);
    favsToolStripMenuItem.DropDown.Items.Add(menu);
    }
}
```

Now, each submenu item has its own event to trigger when clicked. This is how you select which event to trigger based on the name/text of the item,

```cs
void menu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = sender as MenuItem; 
    var menuText = menuItem.Text;

    switch(menuText) {
        case "MenuItem1":
           // menu item1 clicked .. do something 
           break;

        case "MenuItem2":
          // menu item2 clicked .. do something 
          break;
         . ...
}
```